# How shiro authenticate request from non-browser client

Tags: api, rest, shiro, stateless

I have a web site which was secured with shiro. The web site is built with heavy AJAX stuff and REST API.

As I understand, shiro (app server, tomcat) recognize user (client) through cookie (tomcat JSessionID).

Now I'm starting to build an Android App.  How could Shiro (or Tomcat) recognize the client user, since there is no browser to handle cookie automatically?

Should I programmatically handle cookie with HttpClient?  Or is there a better practice about shiro in the scenario of App + RESTful API?